# How can I save a Rhino Tank in my hanger?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I want to steal (and not buy) a tank in GTA 5 Story Mode, and I want to keep it permanently.

I read [here](http://www.ign.com/wikis/gta-5/Vehicle_Storage) that tanks can be saved in my hangar. I've managed to steal one from the military base and drive it all the way to the hangar. I of course have a 5 star wanted level by the time I get there.

I've also managed to put the tank in the hangar and get away in the plane that was already there. **However**, when I came back to enjoy my new tank, it wasn't there.

My suspicion is that you can't save anything in the hangar if you have a wanted level. Is that the case?

#### Update

I realized I could drive to the sewer tunnel opening by the canal, one of the few places big enough to drive the tank in and successfully hide. I did this, and managed to get unwanted again, but when I put my tank in the hangar it didn't stay there. When I came back it was gone. Is it **actually** possible to save tanks in Story Mode?

Comment: Is it not in the list of saved vehicles at the hangar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hangar is for aircraft only... you need to purchase a garage for your cars.